# Simple 21 Game Issue in Python

Tags: python

I recently coded a simple game of 21 (played by the user against the computer,) and am running into some trouble when the user/computer wins the game. The logic behind this program is quite simple and works fine, it's just that after there is a winner (a print statement simply declares the winner once the game is done) the program asks the user if he/she would like to "roll" their dice again. I completely understand why this problem is occurring, but I am unsure of how to fix it *without* using break statements, as my professor does not want us using them. He suggested creating a Boolean flag for my while loop to run, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions? The complete code for my program is listed below. Thank you!

```
import random
GAME_LIMIT = 21

def main():
    user_points = 0
    computer_points = 0
    print("Welcome to the game of 21! May the odds be ever in your favor...")
    print()
    answer = get_response()
    while answer == "y":
        points, comp_points = roll_dice()
        user_points += points
        computer_points += comp_points
        print("Points:", user_points)
        if user_points == GAME_LIMIT:
            print("User's Points:", user_points)
            print("Computer's Points:", computer_points)
            if computer_points == GAME_LIMIT:
                print("Tie Game!")
            else:
                print("User Wins!")
        if user_points > GAME_LIMIT:
            print("User's Points:", user_points)
            print("Computer's Points:", computer_points)
            if computer_points < GAME_LIMIT:
                print("Computer Wins!")
            elif computer_points == GAME_LIMIT:
                print("Computer Wins!")
            else:
                print("Tie Game!")

        answer = get_response()

    if answer == "n":
        print("User's Points:", user_points)
        print("Computer's Points:", computer_points)
        if computer_points == GAME_LIMIT:
            print("Computer Wins!")
        elif computer_points > GAME_LIMIT:
            print("User Wins!")
        elif computer_points == user_points:
            print("Tie Game!")
        elif computer_points < GAME_LIMIT:
            if user_points < computer_points:
                print("Computer Wins!")
            else:
                print("User Wins!")


def roll_dice():
    user_roll = random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)
    computer_roll = random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)
    return user_roll, computer_roll

def get_response():
    response = input("Do you want to roll? (y/n): ")
    return response

main()
```

Comment: You should always include sample output when you can for something like this.

Comment: You could just `return` after someone wins, though admittedly it's not really any different than `break`, which your instructor is against for whatever reason. One boolean approach is to just nest your current `while` loop inside of your check that the game is still running.

Comment: Create a variable called winner set to False. Set it true when there is a winner and then add it to your while loop

Comment: Also, You shouldn't have copy and pasted code for printing the winners.

Comment: After having a winner what should the program do. it should exit  or  what ?

Comment: I appreciate the comments everyone. I know the format of this code isn't the best, our professor wants it to just resemble all of the current concepts (return functions) we are learning, even if it isn't the most "viable." Michael, I tried what you suggested, setting the "winner = True" after there is a winner, after initially declaring "winner = False" before the loop with an if statement saying if winner = False then to execute the loop. However, when "winner" is reassigned after there is a winner, the call to the get_response function is still sequentially executed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: and yes, the program should just simply exit after there is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is if there is a winner or tie end the game 
if you enter n to role the dice still end the game i have added `isEnd` and did some changes(commented)

```
import random
GAME_LIMIT = 21

def roll_dice():
    user_roll = random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)
    computer_roll = random.randint(1,6) + random.randint(1,6)
    return user_roll, computer_roll

def get_response():
    response = raw_input("Do you want to roll? (y/n): ")
    return response


def main():
    user_points = 0
    computer_points = 0
    print("Welcome to the game of 21! May the odds be ever in your favor...")
    print()
    isEnd = False  # added a is game end

    while not isEnd:
        answer = get_response()
        if(answer == "y"): #checkes whther still roll dice
            points, comp_points = roll_dice()
            user_points += points
            computer_points += comp_points
            print("Points:", user_points)
            if user_points == GAME_LIMIT:
                print("User's Points:", user_points)
                print("Computer's Points:", computer_points)
                if computer_points == GAME_LIMIT:
                    print("Tie Game!")
                else:
                    print("User Wins!")
                isEnd = True #When ther is winner
            if user_points > GAME_LIMIT:
                print("User's Points:", user_points)
                print("Computer's Points:", computer_points)
                if computer_points < GAME_LIMIT:
                    print("Computer Wins!")
                elif computer_points == GAME_LIMIT:
                    print("Computer Wins!")
                else:
                    print("Tie Game!")
                isEnd = True #When ther is winner

        if (answer == "n"):
            isEnd = True #or the exit





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```